# Error sendUserActionEvent() mView== null usando progressDialog()

Tags: android, webview-android

Buenas

Pues veran. Tengo una app con un splashscreen (en orientación Portrait) que luego carga un activity cuya orientacion es landscape y se necesita bloquear en esa orientación especifica mientras el usuario este navegando.

Mi activity landscape tiene un webView y un progressdialog que quiero que se muestre mientras el webview hace la carga de la URL.

--EDIT
El webView ya no entra al metodo onReceivedError, el error era un tema de sintaxis en la URL. Sin embargo, el ProgressDialog se queda mostrando incluso aunque ya haya terminado de cargar la página.

El problema esta en que cuando hago el cambio de activities. El webview siempre entra al metodo onReceivedError

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class Main extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{


private ImageButton ibtnRefresh;
private ProgressDialog pd;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private WebView webView;
public static String codeBar = "";

private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

private static final int UI_ANIMATION_DELAY = 300;
private final Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
private View mContentView;
private final Runnable mHidePart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    @Override
    public void run() {
        mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    }
};
private View mControlsView;
private final Runnable mShowPart2Runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Delayed display of UI elements
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.show();
        }
        mControlsView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
};
private boolean mVisible;
private final Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        hide();
    }
};

private final View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (AUTO_HIDE) {
            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
        }
        return false;
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mVisible = true;
    mControlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
    mContentView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.pBar);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ibtnRefresh = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibtnRefresh);
    ibtnRefresh.setOnClickListener(this);
    webView= (WebView)findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
        }
    });

    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                    view.loadUrl("blank");
                    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ibtnRefresh.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    pd.dismiss();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
                    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
                    pd = ProgressDialog.show(Main.this, "Cargando", "Espere por favor...");
                }
                @Override
                public void onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {

                    url = url.replace("%24","$");
                    url = url.replace("%2f","/");
                    url = url.replace("%40","@");
                    if(!url.contains("sendScanReader"))
                    {
                    }else if(!url.contains("Settings")) {

                    }else if(!url.contains("Search")){

                    }else{
                        view.loadUrl(Common.getURL());
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Carga Finalizada",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    if(url.contains("sendScanReader"))
                    {

                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Main2Activity.class);
                        startActivityForResult(i,100);

                    }else if(url.contains("Search")){
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),search.class);
                        startActivity(i);
                    }else if(url.contains("vta")){
                        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),pagosMit.class);
                        startActivityForResult(i,100);
                    }
                    else{
                        Common.setURL(url);
                    }
                    pd.dismiss();
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url);
                }
    });

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

    webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    webView.loadUrl(Common.getURL());

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content);
    String newURL = Common.getURL();
    webview.loadUrl(newURL);
}
```

}

Este es el codigo de mi Manifest.xml, en algunas respuestas encontre que bastaba con agregar la linea de configChanges pero no ha funcionado (lo he probado con y sin el keyboardHidden

```
   <activity
        android:name=".Main"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        android:theme="@style/FullscreenTheme" />
```

Concretamente esto es lo que me muestra el Logcat cada que la aplicación crashea

> D/ViewRootImpl@b313fdb[Main]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 0
>   D/ViewRootImpl@1ca6187[Cargando]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
>   D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=159
>   D/ViewRootImpl@b313fdb[Main]: MSG_WINDOW_FOCUS_CHANGED 1
>   I/InputMethodManager: [IMM] startInputInner - mService.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus
>   D/InputTransport: Input channel constructed: fd=111
>   D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=157
>   E/ViewRootImpl: sendUserActionEvent() mView == null
>   D/ViewRootImpl@e8a1734[SplashLoad]: dispatchDetachedFromWindow
>   D/InputTransport: Input channel destroyed: fd=76

En caso de que influya en algo les comento que la aplicación la estoy haciendo con android Studio y mi equipo de pruebas es un Samsung S7 EDGE

```
compileSdkVersion 26
buildToolsVersion "26.0.1"
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 26
```

Comment: Hola Rodrigo, lo que agregas: android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" es únicamente para no permitir destruir la Activity lo cual sin duda debe funcionar, pero  me parece extraño lo que comentas, puedes buscar en tu logCat algo que mencione "Caused by...." por favor. Como se llama la clase que contiene el codigo que agregaste?

Comment: Hola Jorge. Ya busque en logCat pero no hay ninguna linea que contenga un Caused by.
En cuanto al codigo, todo se encuentra en el onCreate del activity

Comment: Pero como se llama la Activity?

Comment: Es Main (literalmete)

public class Main extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener